# `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found on using ffmpeg

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu, ffmpeg, ubuntu-18.04

I have tried with ffmpeg for video thumbnail creation.Everything working fine when i excute command in ubuntu terminal but it's not working in php codeigniter.

Here is the code i am using

```
$cmd='/usr/bin/ffmpeg  -itsoffset -5  -i  /opt/lampp/htdocs/primalthenics-backend/assets/images/users-images/c67afca9a5e8feffa50f2f69f6b460e9.mp4 -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 400x600  /opt/lampp/htdocs/primalthenics-backend/assets/images/users-images/c67afca9a5e8feffa50f2f69f6b460e9.jpg';
exec($cmd . ' 2>&1 &', $output); 
print_r($output);
```

This error i am getting

```
Array ( [0] => /usr/bin/ffmpeg: /opt/lampp/lib/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16) )
```

i have also search this error but not got the solution.

I am using

```
ubuntu 18.04 
codeigniter 3.0 
php 7.0
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That zlib is installed on your server doesn't necessarily mean that your PHP instance is configured to use it. If you run a `phpinfo();` do you see zlib as part of the PHP installation?

Comment: yes, zlib is enabled..

Answer (score 0):

Have similar issues.
Issue is that PHP is using `/opt/lampp/lib libary` instead of system library used when you run by command line.
Try this and run again:

```
sudo mv /opt/lampp/lib/libz.so.1 /opt/lampp/lib/libz.so.1.orig
```